# Code Igniter Undefined property Controllerclass::$functionname

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, controller

i am practicing CI framework on PHP when i get this error

> Message: Undefined property: Test_controller::$testFunction

My **Test_controller.php** looks like this

```
class Test_controller extends CI_Controller {

public function test(){
    $this->load->model('Test_model');
    $test = $this->Test_model->testFunction;

    echo "Message : " . $test;
}
```

and my **Test_model.php** looks like this

```
class Test_model extends CI_Model{

public function testFunction(){
    return "This is a test function on model";
}
```

I can't find where i made a mistake.

Thanks for answering.

Comment: `testFunction` is a method, please add parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

In `Test_controller`

Add `()` in function `testFunction`

```
class Test_controller extends CI_Controller {

public function test(){
    $this->load->model('Test_model');
    $test = $this->Test_model->testFunction();

    echo "Message : " . $test;
}
```

Comment: Yes this was for testing only, im currently learning.That solve the problem... and that was embarrassing.

Comment: @jeesoon - you shouldn't echo from a controller, just generally speaking.  It's ok for testing but ideally you would pass that data to the view and let it handle the formatting.